# Typescript compilation fails (in Docker) when NODE_ENV=production

Tags: typescript, docker, environment-variables, create-react-app, vercel

So I have a `create-react-app-ts` app that I would like to Dockerize and host on Zeit Now.

Everything works fine locally, running `yarn tsc` and `react-scripts-ts build` works great.

Creating the Docker image also works great from the following Dockerfile:

```
FROM mhart/alpine-node:10.9
WORKDIR /usr/src

ARG REACT_APP_API_ENDPOINT
ARG NODE_ENV

COPY yarn.lock package.json ./
RUN yarn

COPY . .
RUN yarn build && mv build /public
```

However, when publishing to Now, the build script fails on Typescript compilation, outputting compilation errors for most files in the project.

I am able to reproduce that locally as well if I set `ENV NODE_ENV production` in my Dockerfile just above `WORKDIR...`.

So it would seem that either Typescript or `react-scripts-ts` acts differently when `NODE_ENV=production`. I've never encountered this error before, and I don't know how to debug it. Running `NODE_ENV=production tsc` or `NODE_ENV=production react-scripts-ts build` also works fine locally.

I'm running Typescript v 3.0.1 with the following config:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "outDir": "build/dist",
    "module": "esnext",
    "target": "es6",
    "lib": ["es6", "dom", "esnext.asynciterable"],
    "sourceMap": true,
    "allowJs": true,
    "jsx": "react",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "rootDir": "src",
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "noImplicitThis": true,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "strictNullChecks": true,
    "suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors": true,
    "noUnusedLocals": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "strict": true
  },
  "exclude": ["node_modules", "build", "scripts", "acceptance-tests", "webpack", "jest", "src/setupTests.ts"]
}
```

Any advice would be much appreciated! :)

**EDIT**: Added env var args to the Dockerfile. It was originally left out for the sake of brevity, but it ended up being part of the issue and solution

Comment: You should probably post the error message. Is the source code on GitHub? I have a React TS project you can try deploying and start adding in some of your packages to see if/when it fails. https://github.com/styfle/react-server-example-tsx

Answer (score 20, accepted):

So I finally found the issue! In my original `Dockerfile`, `NODE_ENV` was set **before** `yarn install`. This means that for the production build, `yarn` would not install `devDependencies`, and therefore not any of my `@types` libraries. This caused all the compilation errors all over the project.

Moving the definition of `NODE_ENV` **below/after** `yarn install` in the `Dockerfile` solved the issue.

```
FROM mhart/alpine-node:10.9
WORKDIR /usr/src

COPY yarn.lock package.json ./
RUN yarn

ARG REACT_APP_API_ENDPOINT
ARG NODE_ENV

COPY . .
RUN yarn build && mv build /public
```

Note: As far as I know, `yarn build` will make sure to remove the `devDependencies` again, so don't worry about this bloating your build. :)

Comment: This gave me a headache for hours. Thanks!