# Yarn build without installing devDependencies (NODE_ENV=production)

Tags: reactjs, typescript, yarnpkg, storybook

Im working on a Create React App project where our CI runs `yarn install` and `yarn build` with `NODE_ENV` set to `production` in order to skip dealing with `devDependencies` for faster build times.

Our tests, types, and storybook dependencies are `devDependencies` in `package.json`.

This causes errors such as:

```plaintext
Cannot find module '@storybook/react' or its corresponding type declarations.  TS2307

  > 1 | import { ComponentMeta, ComponentStory } from "@storybook/react";
      |                                               ^
    2 | import ...
    3 | import ...
    4 | import ...
```

and

```plaintext
Could not find a declaration file for module 'react'. '/app/.../node_modules/react/index.js' implicitly has an 'any' type.
Try `npm i --save-dev @types/react` if it exists or add a new declaration (.d.ts) file containing `declare module 'react';`  TS7016
 
   > 1 | import { useState, lazy, Suspense } from "react";
       |                                          ^
     2 | 
     3 | import ...
     4 |
```

Is there a way I can configure `yarn build` to ignore storybook and test files when building for production?

One temporary workaround is to set `NODE_ENV` to `production` *after* running `yarn install`, in our CI workflow (similar to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52007806/typescript-compilation-fails-in-docker-when-node-env-production)), but this still feels unnecessary and incorrect (why should we install those dependencies if they are not needed for the build artifact we care about?).

Comment: Is your concern "faster build times" or "minimal build artifact"? Obviously if your tests rely on your devDependencies - which they should - you need to install them in CI during testing. One approach is to separate testing from build/bundling by putting them in different sub-jobs, clearing node_modules and running `yarn install --prod` again after the tests, or copying your repo to e.g. a `build` folder and then run your build process from there.

Comment: Or use a bundler like webpack which optimizes your code by removing devDependencies using tree-shaking - this usually significantly reduces code size anyway so it has more benefits than simply installing with `--prod` flag.

Comment: @JHH thanks for the responses! Webpack is used here already, though I doubt there has been any custom configuration there. I'm certainly no expert in the nitty gritty of webpack. I think the main concern I'm gauging from the team is CI job time.

We have a separate job that runs the tests, as you mentioned.

What I'm lost on is what the use of `yarn install` with `NODE_ENV=production` is, given that subsequent commands like `build` depend on a non-prod install.

Comment: It's a bit surprising that your devDeps would contribute to job time that badly. Is there anything you could do with regards to caching? The CI pipelines I've used are mostly Travis and AWS CodeBuild and they both offer caching to speed up consecutive jobs. Would it help installing the build tools globally with regards to caching? You might also want to consider splitting jobs up to be run on parallel, if architecture and tool/subscription plan allows for it.

Comment: Obviously I'm looking from the outside and don't know how bad your build times are  but it sounds a bit like optimizing by skipping dev dependencies may not be the best choice. Especially since they are by definition needed to, well, build and test your app. 